# Calculate Radiant Intensity from Radiant Power and estimated Radiant Distrubution of infrared LED

Tags: optics, light-emitting-diodes, radiometry

Consider the infrared led [TSAL7600](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Vishay%20Semiconductors/TSAL7600.pdf) which has the following properties:

$$ \Phi = 35 mW $$
$$ I_e = 25 mW/sr $$

The half angle is $30^\circ$ and:

$$ I_r(\theta) = cos^{4.818}(\theta) $$

is a good approximation for the relative radiant intensity.

[image: approximation-vs-datasheet]

However, finding the actual radiant intensity is eluding me.  I'm looking for something like:

$$ I(\theta) = I_e \cdot I_r(\theta)$$

where $I_e$ is the peak intensity.  If it's correct, then integrating over the surface of the relative radiant intensity should give the radiant power:

$$\Phi = \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi \int_{0}^{\pi/2}I_e cos^{4.818}(\theta) sin(\theta) d\theta $$

$$\Phi = 2\pi I_e \int_{0}^{\pi/2} cos^{4.818}(\theta) sin(\theta) d\theta $$

And thanks to [integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/)

$$ \Phi = I_e \cdot 1.0799 $$
$$ \Phi = 26.997 \neq 35 $$

That's obviously nowhere close.

The above integral came out of a paper called [Improvement of the Approximation Accuracy of LED Radiation Patterns](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331933510_Improvement_of_the_Approximation_Accuracy_of_LED_Radiation_Patterns/fulltext/5c93950245851506d7211dfe/Improvement-of-the-Approximation-Accuracy-of-LED-Radiation-Patterns.pdf?origin=publication_detail), but I had already found $cos^{4.818}(\theta)$ by playing around in octave so I didn't use a nice round number like 5 (with a nice solution).  I presume the integral finds the surface area of the radiation pattern since I've seen similar elsewhere, but I don't claim to know what I'm doing.

In the paper, they use the radiant power to solve for $I_o$, the maximum intensity, which I believe is the same thing as $I_e$.

Could someone kindly point out what I'm doing wrong?

The goal here is to go from $\Phi=35mW$ to $I_e=25mW/sr$ using the estimated radiant distribution.

Actually the real goal is to figure out the radiant intensity over the angle subtended by the apparent size of the die ($1.8mm$ according to the datasheet).  I think this information will help me with a different question regarding eye safety of infra red LEDs.

---

Additional info.

This integral:

$$\Phi = 2\pi I_e \int_{0}^{\pi/2} cos^{4.818}(\theta) sin(\theta) d\theta $$

evaluates to $\approx 1$ and I need $\approx 1.4$ to get the correct radiant power.  That means one of four possibilities:

1. the integral $$\Phi = \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\phi \int_{0}^{\pi/2}I_e cos^{n}(\theta) sin(\theta) d\theta $$
   is not the correct integral to use
2. the datasheet distribution does not match the real distribution.  If the actual half angle were more like $35^\circ$ for which $cos^{3.487}(\theta)$ is a better fit, the integral evaluates to $\approx 1.4$.
3. the actual distribution is not approximated well enough by $cos^{4.818}(\theta)$
4. the required 'fudge factor' is $1.4\approx \sqrt{2}$.  Is it possible that $I_e$ should be multiplied by $\sqrt{2}$ first?

It would be helpful if someone could confirm that item 1 is true or false.